# Why such a complicated counterexample to differentiable function, which has discontinuous partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

[Here](http://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives) a counterexample is given, that a differentiable function has not necessarily continuous partial derivatives, but I asked myself why such a complicated example is given? Would simply
$$
 f(x) = |x|
$$
not work? It is differentiable, but its derivative is not continuous, quite simple example (or its multidimensional analogue $f(x) = ||x|| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ if you will). Why this complicated
$$
 f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x) 
$$
for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) := 0$ (or its multidimensional form presented in the link). What is gained by presenting this complicated example? Maybe I have overlooked something...

Comment: $|x|$ is *not* differentiable at $0$.

Comment: yes, that it... completely overlooked o_O

Comment: Here's a fun fact: The derivative of a differentiable function, even though it may be discontinuous, satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Nice, found it under the name *Darboux's Theorem*, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis) ;)

Comment: Ah, right. I had forgotten what name was attached to the theorem, though I knew the result. Kind of silly, given that I just lectured on the Darboux integral last week. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is finding a *differentiable* function that isn't continuously differentiable. The absolute value function $\lvert x \rvert$ is not differentiable at $0$, and so doesn't provide an example.